# Guidance in choosing a cms platform

Tags: javascript, database, web, content-management-system, e-commerce

What CMS is best to use if client needs:

1. user registration (pay first to become member)
2. e-commerce functionalities with creditcard and iDeal payments
3. users able to fill, PAY and submit custom forms with file upload to the database with 
   unique id to retrieve and display back in the front end pages
4. most important is easily create custom fields, with unique id’s and be able to retrieve the
   data back for display in the front end
5. commenting feature with file upload ability (form/post/blog/forum like)

The CMS must support these 5 options.

Any experts have good suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a custom script, I doubt if you can get such script without modifying it. I'd try with:

- Drupal,
- Joomla
- (even) WordPress

For all of them, plugins should help much.